# how to create a download link in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, download

I need to creat a download link in PHP for some files that are stored other than my server accessible location ie. in filesystem location on the server device itself.
when i provide the file system location in the hyperlink tab the link seems to have the file system location but does not get download.What can be done.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That will never work, you can only hyperlink to a URL not a full path. Otherwise anyone could access your sensitive data on your server.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ob_clean_all ()
{
$ob_active = ob_get_length ()!== FALSE;
while($ob_active)
{
    ob_end_clean();
    $ob_active = ob_get_length ()!== FALSE;
}
return FALSE;
}

function forcedownload($fileName, $filePath, $fileSize, $fileExt)
{

if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

switch($fileExt)
{
    case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
    case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
    case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
    case "doc": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-word"; break;
    case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
    case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}
ob_clean_all();
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName.";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ". $fileSize);
readfile($filePath);
exit();
}
```

Use this function forcedownload and pass the respective parameters.